# azure pipeline env not found

Tags: python, azure-devops

```
trigger:
- master

jobs:

- job: build

  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

  steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: '3.6'

  - task: PythonScript@0
    inputs:
      scriptSource: 'inline'
      script: |
        import os
        print(os.environ.get('account_name')) # NONE
        print(os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_NAME')) # NONE
        print(os.environ.get('account_name_var')) # NONE

  - script: echo $(ACCOUNT_NAME) # Print *** can be accessed

    env:
        account_name_var: $(account_name)
```

#### How to map private variables to the environment?

#### os.environ not found ACCOUNT_NAME variable

#### Bash can output ACCOUNT_NAME variable

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the environment variables under the script that you want to print them. Check the example below:

```
  - script: |
      python env.py
    displayName: 'env'
    env:
      account_name_var: $(account_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your PythonScript task like this:

```
- task: PythonScript@0
  displayName: 'Run a Python script'
  inputs:
    scriptSource: inline
    script: |
     import os
     print(os.environ.get('ACCOUNT_NAME'))
  env:
    ACCOUNT_NAME: $(account_name)
```